# AngularFireMessaging - Error this._next is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

In my angular Application i wanted to add some web-push-notifications with firebase.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireMessaging } from "@angular/fire/messaging";
import { mergeMapTo } from "rxjs/operators";


@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"],
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {}

  requestPermission() {
    this.afMessaging.requestPermission
      .pipe(mergeMapTo(this.afMessaging.tokenChanges))
      .subscribe(
        (token) => {
          console.log("Permission granted! Save to the server!", token);

          this.afMessaging.messages.subscribe(
            (message) => {
              console.log(message);
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log("error", error);
            }
          );
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );


  }
}
```

I can get a Token and in the developer Console under Application are Notification Requests, when I send a test Message via Firebase.

But in my Console I get this error:

```
zone-evergreen.js:659 Unhandled Promise rejection: this._next is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: ServiceWorkerContainer.addEventListener:message ; Value: TypeError: this._next is not a function
    at WindowController.next [as onMessageCallback] (Subscriber.js:49)
    at WindowController.<anonymous> (index.esm.js:1067)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at tslib.es6.js:74
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:960)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:70)
    at WindowController.push../node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.esm.js.WindowController.messageEventListener (index.esm.js:1056)
    at ServiceWorkerContainer.<anonymous> (index.esm.js:890)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399) TypeError: this._next is not a function
```

I am using Angular 9 and angular/fire and firebase.

Comment: try this  FirebasePlugin.onMessageReceived((response)

Answer (score 1):

You must have `firebase` library version greater than `7.16` inside your `package.json` and it should match the version in `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

I found the solution is detailed [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2299#issuecomment-662405207).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is library core issues, and there is two options to avoid error:

1. From [stackoverflow.com/a/60557818/7927724](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60557818/7927724) i tried to go with these versions and it works fine. You can try it for now until you will find out problem with actual versions
2. You can try this workaround:

```js
this.afMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
    (_messaging: any) => {
        messaging._next = (payload: any) = > {
            console.log(payload);
        };
    }
);
```